# How to programmatically set pragma in RenderScript

Tags: pragma, renderscript

I am working on a RenderSript project. In RenderScript, I can relax the floating point precision by `#pragma rs_fp_imprecise`. However, I do not want low precision in all cases. Is there any way to set the pragma programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

No. The pragma is used (and can only be used) for the entire file. Please also note that you should really not be using rs_fp_imprecise at all. Please use rs_fp_relaxed if you don't need full IEEE-754 conforming behavior. rs_fp_imprecise came into existence to theoretically support low-end GPGPU drivers, but those have not really materialized. All of the existing RS GPGPU drivers will accelerate rs_fp_relaxed code, so that is most likely the appropriate value to use these days (assuming you can tolerate some loss of precision).